# jCarousel controls not working, issue with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jcarousel

So I'm attempting to create a jCarousel that can navigate between images, I'm having issue with the JavaScript controls for navigating the carousel, nothing is happening when the "next" navigation control is clicked on the carousel. Any help on where I'm going wrong would be greatly appreciated. I've been using the examples provided with jCarousel to help but I'm still not getting it. 
EDIT- The CSS is fine and working correctly

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./scripts/jquery-ui-themes-1.11.3/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">      
<script src="./scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../dist/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>


<div id ="content">
    <div id="welcomeMessage">
    WELCOME! Select a quiz type from the menu above to get started!
    </div>
    <div id="slideshowQuiz">            
        Slideshow Quiz
        <div id="jcarousel" class="jcarousel">
            <ul>
            <li><p>QUESTION 1</p><img src="./images/niagrafalls.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt="">   </li>
            <li><img src="./images/brooklynbridge.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt=""> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-prev">&lsaquo;</a>
        <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-next">&rsaquo;</a>
        <p class="jcarousel-pagination">
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
})

function slideshowQuizContent()
{
    $('#slideshowQuiz').show();
    $('#welcomeMessage').hide();
    slideshowQuiz();
}

function slideshowQuiz()
{
    (function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('.jcarousel').jcarousel();

        $('.jcarousel-control-prev')
            .on('jcarouselcontrol:active', function() {
                $(this).removeClass('inactive');
            })
            .on('jcarouselcontrol:inactive', function() {
                $(this).addClass('inactive');
            })
            .jcarouselControl({
                target: '-=1'
            });

        $('.jcarousel-control-next')
            .on('jcarouselcontrol:active', function() {
                $(this).removeClass('inactive');
            })
            .on('jcarouselcontrol:inactive', function() {
                $(this).addClass('inactive');
            })
            .jcarouselControl({
                target: '+=1'
            });

        $('.jcarousel-pagination')
            .on('jcarouselpagination:active', 'a', function() {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            })
            .on('jcarouselpagination:inactive', 'a', function() {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            })
            .jcarouselPagination();
    });
})(jQuery);             
}
```

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific about what "not working" and "having issue" means? What exactly is not happening that is supposed to be happening?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Sorry, the navigation controls aren't working. The buttons are displayed fine but nothing happens when the next navigation button on the carousel is clicked.

Comment: A the top of your javascript you have `$(document).ready(function(){ })` with nothing in it. Usually with JQuery stuff I see all the other functions inside that. I see that `slideshowQuizContent()` calls `slideshowQuiz()`, but when does `slideshowQuizContent()` get called?